# Matching text in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am creating a label system on Excel where it takes the product (e.g. Oranges) and compares it to columns of product (e.g. one lists fruits and other berries) and labels it with either fruit or berries according to which column it is in.

VLookup and HLookup are problematic since the reference table will have to be rearranged which is problematic. It won't work without rearrangement as the "Type" I need is on the first row of HLookup and also the fact that there are 2 columns of data to look through. The 2 columns of data also messes up the MATCH function as it can only look through 1 column. I don't really want to wind down to a lot of IF statements which is the reason for my question here.

There is some code that performs similar to what I need but MMULT function won't work for my reference table because of having so many rows of data.

The code creates a matrix type of thing and finds which row it is in instead of column.

`=INDEX(TYPE,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(SUB_TYPE=C2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(SUB_TYPE)^0)),0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

[image]

[image]

`INDEX` and `MATCH` combo can still do the trick for you. Like so:

```
=INDEX(A1:B1,,SUMPRODUCT((A1:B4=D2)*COLUMN(A1:B4)))
```

You can even make it fancy with `CHOOSE`:

```
=CHOOSE(SUMPRODUCT((A1:B4=D2)*COLUMN(A1:B4)),"Fruits","Berries")
```

Possibly better would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,D2)>0,"Fruits","Berries")
```

will do if you certain there is a match in either column. If you not sure, and want to know if there actually is a match you could stack another `IF`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,D2)>0,"Fruits",IF(COUNTIF(B:B,D2)>0,"Berries","No match found"))
```

Suggested edit would be even faster:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"Fruits",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,B:B,0)),"Berries","No match found"))
```

Comment: I think the last one was the best, I would only change to using `ISNUMBER(MATCH())` only because MATCH is quicker and if the search set is large it will bog the calcs down and after about 10,000 formulas it stops working all together.